# android my viewModel update the list internally but recyclerview does't reflects the changes

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to view my files using recycler view and MVVM, the problem is that `memoryViewModel` doesn't reflect the changes on `memoryItemsRecyclerViewAdapter`

```
memoryViewModel!!.mutableLiveData?.observe(this.viewLifecycleOwner) {
            memoryItemsRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() //this should show the list items of the recycler view
            Log.d("view model result", it.size.toString()) // log message shows the list items
        }
```

so, the final question is why the `mutableLiveData!!.postValue(mutableList)` don't update the recycler view?
here is a sample of my code

the fragment

```
class MemoryFragment: Fragment() {
    companion object{
        private var rootDirectory: java.io.File? = null
        var currentFolder = rootDirectory
        private var filesList: MutableList<File?>? = mutableListOf()
        private var memoryViewModel: MemoryViewModel? = null
    }
    private var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences? = null
    private lateinit var listView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var pathsRecyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var searchView: androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
    private lateinit var refreshSwipe: SwipeRefreshLayout
    private lateinit var memoryItemsRecyclerViewAdapter: MemoryItemsRecyclerViewAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        sharedPreferences = androidx.preference.PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(requireContext())

        val memoryViewModelProvider = MemoryViewModelProvider()
        memoryViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, memoryViewModelProvider).get(MemoryViewModel::class.java)
        
//        rootDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
//        currentFolder = rootDirectory
//        val rootFoldersList = rootDirectory?.listFiles()?.toMutableList()
//        for (item in rootFoldersList!!)
//            if(item.isDirectory)
//                filesList?.add(File(R.drawable.ic_folders, item, item.totalSpace))
//            else
//                filesList?.add(File(R.drawable.ic_file, item, item.totalSpace))
//        memoryViewModel = MemoryViewModel(filesList!!)
//        MemoryViewModel.lazyMemoryViewModel
    }
    
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(requireContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_memory, container, false)
        listView = view.findViewById(R.id.list_view)
        pathsRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view)
        searchView = view.findViewById(R.id.search_view)
        refreshSwipe = view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh)
        listView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)

        memoryItemsRecyclerViewAdapter = MemoryItemsRecyclerViewAdapter(memoryViewModel!!, requireContext(), filesList!!)

        listView.adapter = memoryItemsRecyclerViewAdapter

        memoryViewModel!!.mutableLiveData?.observe(this.viewLifecycleOwner) {
            memoryItemsRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            Log.d("view model result", it.size.toString())

        }
        return view
    }
}
```

the viewModel

```
class MemoryViewModel(private var mutableList: MutableList<com.example.everyentertainment.models.File?>?): ViewModel() {
private val foldersPath: MutableList<String?>? = null
private val foldersName: MutableList<String?>? = null
private var rootDirectory: File? = null
var mutableLiveData: MutableLiveData<MutableList<com.example.everyentertainment.models.File?>>? = null

companion object{
    var currentFolder: File? = null
}

init {
    val job = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        if (mutableLiveData == null) mutableLiveData = MutableLiveData()
        if(mutableList == null) mutableList = mutableListOf()
        initializeMemoryFragment()
    }
    job.start()
    job.invokeOnCompletion {
        mutableLiveData!!.postValue(mutableList)//postValue() doesn't update UI also I tried mutableLiveData.value = mutableList but it throws OnCompletionHandlerException
        Log.d("mutable list size", mutableList!!.size.toString())
        Log.d("mutable live data size", mutableLiveData!!.value.toString())
    }
}

fun initializeMemoryFragment(){
    rootDirectory = getExternalStorageDirectory()
    currentFolder = rootDirectory
    val filesList = rootDirectory!!.listFiles()
    for(position in filesList!!.indices)
        if(filesList[position].isDirectory)
            mutableList!!.add(com.example.everyentertainment.models.File(R.drawable.ic_folders,
                filesList[position], getFolderSize(filesList[position])))
        else
            mutableList!!.add(com.example.everyentertainment.models.File(R.drawable.ic_file,
                filesList[position], getFolderSize(filesList[position])))
}

 fun getFolderSize(file: File): Long{
    if(!file.exists())
        return 0
    if(!file.isDirectory)
        return file.length()
    val dirs: MutableList<File> = LinkedList()
    dirs.add(file)
    var result: Long = 0
    while (!dirs.isEmpty()) {
        val dir = dirs.removeAt(0)
        if (!dir.exists()) continue
        val listFiles = dir.listFiles()
        if (listFiles == null || listFiles.isEmpty()) continue
        for (child in listFiles) {
            result += child.length()
            if (child.isDirectory) dirs.add(child)
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

and finally the recycler view adapter

```
class MemoryItemsRecyclerViewAdapter(private val memoryViewModel: MemoryViewModel, private val context: Context, private val dataSet: MutableList<File?>?):
RecyclerView.Adapter<MemoryItemsRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
/**
 * Provide a reference to the type of views that you are using
 * (custom ViewHolder).
 */
class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    val fileNameTextView: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.name_text_view)
    val sizeTextView: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.size_text_view)
    val numberOfFilesTextView: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.number_of_files_text_view)
    val dateTextView: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.date_text_view)
    val imageView: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.image_view)

    init {
    // Define click listener for the ViewHolder's View.

    }
}

// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    // Create a new view, which defines the UI of the list item
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context).inflate(R.layout.memory_list_view_item, viewGroup, false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    // Get element from your dataset at this position and replace the
    // contents of the view with that element
    val file = dataSet!![position]
    viewHolder.fileNameTextView.text = file!!.file.name
    viewHolder.sizeTextView.text = memoryViewModel.readableFileSize(dataSet[position]!!.size)
    viewHolder.dateTextView.text = memoryViewModel.getFolderDateModified(file.file)
    viewHolder.numberOfFilesTextView.text = memoryViewModel.getSubFoldersQuantity(context, file.file)
    if(file.file.isDirectory)
        viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_folders)
    else
        viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_file)
}

// Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
override fun getItemCount() = dataSet!!.size
```

}

Comment: You're not updating ``dataSet`` in the ``RecyclerView``, so it has no new data to display. You need to pass the new data to the adapter, and then call ``notifyDataSetChanged()``

Comment: @cactustictacs I guess that recyclerview should update the UI dynamically, any ways I see that the problem is mutableLiveData!!.postValue(mutableList) doesn't send the new list to the adapter observer, in other words, the data are updated internally only

Comment: You're supposed to ``observe`` your ``LiveData`` and react to the new values as they arrive, in your case by passing them to the adapter. Right now your adapter just uses what you initialise it with, in ``dataSet``, and that never changes so you'll never see a change in the ``RecyclerView``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your adapter is hardcoded to display the contents of `dataSet` (you fetch from it in `onBindViewHolder`, you reference it in `getItemCount`) and you never change those contents, so there's never anything to update. The `RecyclerView` will only ever display what you first passed in. You need to make the adapter's data updateable, I'd recommend something like this:

```
class MemoryItemsRecyclerViewAdapter(
    private val memoryViewModel: MemoryViewModel,
    private val context: Context,
    private var dataSet: List<File?> = emptyList() // this is a var now, and not a mutable list
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MemoryItemsRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    // this function replaces the current data with the new set, and refreshes the UI
    fun setData(newData: List<File?>) {
        dataSet = newData
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    ...
}
```

Now you have a way to update the adapter, and it takes care of updating the UI itself - it's better to have the logic (like calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`) in here, because really the adapter should be deciding what's changed and how to handle it.

I made `dataSet` a `var` so you can just swap the old list for the new one, and made them immutable `List`s since they don't need to be mutable. I added `emptyList()` as a default - it doesn't need to be nullable, and you're treating it as non-null (with `!!` everywhere) anyway, so just make it non-null. If you really want, you can make it a mutable list and do it that way - in that case, use `mutableListOf()` for the empty default instead

---

So now you can update the adapter, you just need to do that in your observer function:

```
memoryViewModel!!.mutableLiveData?.observe(this.viewLifecycleOwner) { newData ->
    // when a new list comes in, set it on the adapter
    memoryItemsRecyclerViewAdapter.setData(newData)
    Log.d("view model result", newData.size.toString())
}
```

and that's it. Your observer just reacts to new values as they come in (which includes any current value, when you first `observe` the `LiveData`) so you just need to do whatever with them

(Also, you're really complicating things by making everything nullable, especially when you're assuming they're all non-null when you access them anyway with `!!`)

Comment: I really appreciate your help but I think you didn't get my point, the data that I'm trying to view is the initial list which comes from the init block in the viewModel, and for the complexity that you mentioned I guess you are right and that because I'm new to kotlin. Again and again thank you very much and I'm happy with this discussion

Comment: @AhmedGamal Are you saying the ``Log.d("view model result", it.size.toString())`` line doesn't run?

Comment: no it's running and returning the size and the elements of the list,

Comment: @AhmedGamal so you're getting the data you want to display then? The initial list generated from the ``init`` block? That's what you're logging the size of?

Comment: yes exactly the initial list is that generated from init block and that's what I want to show

Comment: @AhmedGamal well that's what the answer's showing you how to do - create a way of updating the data in the adapter, use that when you get the data in the observer. Then when you set a list on the LiveData, it fires the observer, which updates the adapter, which displays the new data. I'm not sure what you think I've missed?

Comment: I don't know why your solution didn't work for me the first time but when I just copy and paste it works so I guess that I was missing something, can you please explain for me this line `newData -> memoryItemsRecyclerViewAdapter.setData(newData)` especially newData -> cause as I said I'm new to kotlin and thank you very much for your patience

Comment: @AhmedGamal ``newData ->`` is just naming the variable that's being passed into the observer lambda (the function) - it's called ``it`` by default, I just wanted to give it an explicit name to make it clearer what's happening. Maybe ``newList`` would be better